# Dealing with RSS in JSON

Tags: json, ios8, rss

I have a JSON data being called in async my has problem is, how does one call the title from all within the tag

```
{
"rss": {
"channel": {
    "atom:link": "",
    "title": "The Local",
    "link": "http://www.thelocal.se/",
    "description": "Sweden's news in English",
    "language": "en-us",
    "managingEditor": "TheLocal",
    "webMaster": "TheLocal",
    "generator": "TheLocal RSS Feed Generator",
    "item": {
        "title": "Knausgård savages the 'Cyclops' Swedes",
        "description": "Norwegian literary star Karl Ove Knausgård has launched an extraordinary attack on the Swedes, damning them as a race of narrow-minded “cyclops” who cannot tolerate ambiguity, have no understanding of literature, and are “full of hate and fear”.",
        "link": "http://www.thelocal.se/20150520/knausgrd-savages-the-cyclops-swedes",
        "pubDate": "2015-05-20 15:25:25",
        "guid": "http://www.thelocal.se/20150520/knausgrd-savages-the-cyclops-swedes"
    },
    "item": {
        "title": "Migration Board worker took bribes for passports",
        "description": "A court in Malmö has jailed a former Migration Board worker and his accomplice for taking bribes in exchange for residence permits and passports for asylum seekers desperate to stay in Sweden.",
        "link": "http://www.thelocal.se/20150520/two-found-guilty-in-migration-board-bribery-case",
        "pubDate": "2015-05-20 12:32:46",
        "guid": "http://www.thelocal.se/20150520/two-found-guilty-in-migration-board-bribery-case"
    },
    "item": {
        "title": "Two million Swedes design 'house of clicks'",
        "description": "A team of award-winning architects have joined forces with two million Swedes to design the country’s most sought-after home.",
        "link": "http://www.thelocal.se/20150520/two-million-swedes-design-dream-house-of-clicks",
        "pubDate": "2015-05-20 12:01:35",
        "guid": "http://www.thelocal.se/20150520/two-million-swedes-design-dream-house-of-clicks"
    },
```

And what I have now is:

```
if var jsonArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? NSDictionary {

                            println("jsonArray: \(jsonArray)")

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                for var i:Int = 0; i < 10; i++ {

                                    var title:String = jsonArray.valueForKeyPath("rss.channel.item.title") as String
                                    self.tableData.append(title)
                                    var content:String = jsonArray.valueForKeyPath("rss.channel.item.description") as String
                                    self.detail.append(content)
                                    self.rssTable.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
```

The problem is, that no matter what way I think of it, I can't call multiple items as the json is not sorted and using an array in some form might be the answer.

Any thoughts how I can solve the data. The data is going into an array called tableData then displayed in a table.

Comment: Also there are two feeds one with item and other with item:1 and so on, how would I get it to process both?

Comment: I thk iOS cannot have multiple objects with same key in a dictionary. Do you have control on the service providing the JSON data? You should change the **"item"** tag to **"items"** and put an array as its content.

Comment: The source is thelocal.fr so i have no control

Comment: I tried and get the RSS feeds, the are in XML format. How do you get them in JSON format ?

Comment: @RicetongTan How I did it was using the RSS_PHP function http://rssphp.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution that works with ALL RSS feeds.

```
for var i:Int = 0; i < 10; i++ {

                                    var title:String = jsonArray.valueForKeyPath("rss.channel.item:\(i).title") as String
                                    self.tableData.append(title)
                                    var content:String = jsonArray.valueForKeyPath("rss.channel.item:\(i).description") as String
                                    self.detail.append(content)
                                    var link:String = jsonArray.valueForKeyPath("rss.channel.item:\(i).link") as String
                                    self.linkData.append(link)

                                    self.rssTable.reloadData()
                                }
```